# Artifactory cleanup - what is the right way to clean conan packages and docker images?

Tags: docker, artifactory, conan, resource-cleanup

I'm working on an Artifactory Cleanup script.
I wanted to know what is the right way to clean/delete Conan packages and Docker images.
Should I use Conan/Docker CLI or can I simply delete the relevant folders from artifactory with JFrog CLI or rest?
Using JFrog CLI will delete all relevant metadata as well?

Thanks!

didn't try anything yet. I'm asking here because I want to make my script as simple as possible and I don't want it to depend on external tools. Just on Artifactory/JFrog calls.

Comment: Conan packages can be removed directly in Artifactory, as long as you remove the full folder, not individual files. For example you cannot remove the ``conanfile.py`` or the ``export`` subfolder, but leave the package binaries under ``package`` (the opposite is possible, you can remove ``package``, but leave the ``export`` folder with only the recipe. The metadata is also stored in files like index.json, that will be removed with the folder, and other possible metadata as properties will be removed too, so you would be safe.

Answer (score 3):

There is a cleanup plugin out of the box provided by JFrog [here](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup).
Of course, you can take it and change it per your requirements.

As for Docker, there is a proposed solution [here](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-clean-up-old-docker-images/).
You can also use the CLi's, but if you want more complex logic, you may want to use the Artifactory Query Language, the above solutions both use this logic.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am using AQL to get the list of artifacts I want to delete (based on upload date and offset for the minimum number of artifacts/folders we want to save). my question is more about weather it is safe to delete folders with Conan packages and Docker images un the same way I'm deleting regular artifacts.

Comment: I am not familiar with any special use case for Conan during cleanup.
As for Docker - One image can be associated with several artifacts (manifest and layers), so of course, when you clean an image, you need to take care of all the relevant artifacts associated with it, but the script I have shared should take care of it and you can also customize it.